# How to use external font families in BIRT Reports?

Tags: fonts, birt, font-family

I'm using BIRT version 4.5.0. I want to use some specific font families (more specifically 'Open Sans') in reports. In the mentioned version of BIRT is supported few font families only and also I'm not able to add external font families by API and also by design. Is any APIs or JAR files available to handle external font families? Also kindly expecting the procedure (code) to handle that font families. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

```
ReportDesignHandle designHandle = session.createDesign();

IncludedCssStyleSheet sheet =  StructureFactory.createIncludedCssStyleSheet();
sheet.setExternalCssURI("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans");
sheet.setUseExternalCss(true);
designHandle.addCss(sheet); 

StyleHandle newStyle = designHandle.getElementFactory().newStyle("group-header");
newStyle.setProperty(StyleHandle.FONT_FAMILY_PROP, "Open Sans");
newStyle.setProperty(StyleHandle.COLOR_PROP, "#676767");
designHandle.getStyles().add(newStyle);
```

It is working for me. May help to you.